# return custom QGraphicsItem by itemAt() or collidingItems()

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I create my own class:

```
class myTile : public QGraphicsItem{}
```

I add these `myTile` in a `QGraphicsScene`. Every `myTile` has a value and a getter for the value. Now I want to get a `myTile` and read its value.

I tried `collidingItems()` and `itemAt()`, but the problem is: These two method can only return `QGraphicsItem`. The `QGraphicsItem` doesn't have my return value method in `myTile`. Is there a way to get a custom item?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
myTile *t = (myTile*)myScene->itemAt(i);
t->myMethod();
```

Comment: (myTile*)scene->itemAt(25,25,QTransform)->getValue();

Comment: Sorry, my first example was wrong and I edited it. Try new version please :)